# Bookdown how to change the title styles based on titles names

Tags: css, r, r-markdown

I have a book with
h2 titles that are always the same in my book chapters :

h1 : text mining
h2 : course
h2 : tutorial

h1 : programming with R
h2 : course
h2 : tutorial

...

I want to change the title styles based on titles names :

for exemple :
green text color for h2 "course" (and h3 h4, ...)

blue text color for h2 "tutorial" (and h3 h4, ...)

The body text will be unchanged

h1 : text mining
h2 : course (green style)
h2 : tutorial (blue style)

h1 : programming with R
h2 : course (green style)
h2 : tutorial (blue style)

...

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you can use classes for tags.

Comment: @s.kuznetsov Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use classes for `h` tags. Each class contains a specific color.

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}

.yellow {
  color: yellow;
}

.green {
  color: green;
}

.blue {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="red">text mining</h1>
<h2 class="green">course (green style)<h2> 
<h2 class="blue">tutorial (blue style)<h2>

<h1 class="yellow">programming with R</h1> 
<h2 class="green">course (green style)</h2> 
<h2 class="blue">tutorial (blue style)</h2>
```

Comment: @ How can I use class in Bookdown?

Comment: @Wilcar, Show pls the structure of your code in Bookdown. how the headings are arranged, etc.

Comment: Ok I found a solution unsing div in css div.blue for exemples and `:::cours 

#### Cours {-} :::` in bookdown

Comment: @Wilcar, Okay. It will be very helpful to many if you show the structure of the code in your question. So that a person with a possible problem could be based on your question.